# Screen Reader Friendly Console Error Logs

Tags: debugging, console, accessibility, screen-readers

Does anyone know of a browser that has a screen reader friendly debugging console? I have a friend whose a blind programmer and it drives her nuts that she can't easily "see" the console log errors.

Answer (score 0):

This drives me nuts also. Unfortunately, the best solution for now is IE 10. This is awful what they did to IE 11 but I hope to convince them to make this more accessible.
And yes, I'm working with JAWS, so it might be different for NVDA, Window Eyes or Supernova.

Comment: She's using JAWS too but it doesn't work well for her. Do you a special shortcut to get better results from it?

Comment: Nope, you only have to press F12, search for Start debugging there, and then view the console log(.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Firebug for Firefox. After installing it, in the Web Developer menu of the tools menu, go into Firebug, Options, then turn on the accessibility enhancements. Some bits aren't perfect, but the console window at least is. It has a list of log rows that can be navigated with the up/down arrows and then a bit for typing in your own js commands. To get to the Firebug window when you open it with F12, use F6. Also works for getting out of it too.

Hope this works for your friend as well as its worked for me.